# how to have jest resolve promises in order different than promises were called?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am using Axios to do requests to my server. I am aware of how to mock Axios and supply positive and negative results to my code under test. But today I ran into a case where my code calls two api end points and to test the logic properly, I need to be able to control the order that they are resolved in.

Without doing anything special, I jest will resolve the first call first and then resolve the second call. But I need to ensure that my code can handle the calls being resolved in the opposite order. I can't figure out how to get jest to resolve the second call before resolving the first call.

A simple example of the code under test would be:

```
function underTest() { 
   axios.request('get', url1).then(() => { do something });
   axios.request('get', url2).then(() => { do something else });
}
```

I have to ensure that the code does the right thing when having "do something" and "do something else" run in both sequences.

@Bergi asked how I am mocking the Axios requests now, so here goes.

In my production code I use NTypewriter to create Typescript classes for each C# controller I have on the back end. It produces something like this:

```
export class LeagueService {
     public static getManagementSummaryRoute = (leagueId: number) => `/api/League/${leagueId}/ManagementSummary`;
     public static getManagementSummary(leagueId: number) : Promise<LeagueManagementSummary> {
         return MakeRequest<LeagueManagementSummary>("get", this.getManagementSummaryRoute(leagueId), null);
}
```

where MakeRequest<> is:

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse, Method } from 'axios';

export async function MakeRequest<T>(httpMethod: Method, url: string, 
payload: any | undefined = null): Promise<T>
{
  const r = await axios.request({
    method: httpMethod,
    url,
    data: payload
  });
  return r.data;
}
```

This lets me call out to the end point like this:

```
  BoxLeagueService.getSession(this.leagueId, this.sessionId)
    .then((newData: SessionBox) => {
      box.updateData(newData);
    })
    .catch();
```

Ok, then in the unit test code, I have to import axios and mock it. Jest has great support for axios.

```
import axios from 'axios';
jest.mock('axios');
const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;
```

then in a test, I do something like this:

```
it('constructor should request the league info with live layout When preview is false', () => {
   // Arrange
   mockedAxios.request.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: leagueInfo });
   mockedAxios.request.mockClear();
   // Act
   model = new BLInfoModel(leagueIdStr, false);
   // Assert
   expect(mockedAxios.request).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
     method: 'get',
     url: BoxLeagueService.infoPageRoute(leagueId, false),
     data: null
   });
});
```

the data: leagueInfo is the data that I am supplying from the server. I store these in .json files in a folder called **json** so that I can find them easily and add to them easily.

I just import them into my unit test at the top of the file like this:

```
// Test Data
import leagueInfo from './__json__/LeagueInfo.json';
```

This all works great when I am happy having jest fulfill the axios requests in the order that they are called. But today, after many years of doing this, I ran across a situation where I wanted to test that resolving two requests in the opposite order still produced the proper result.

Comment: Can you show us how you are currently mocking `axios.request`?

Answer (score 0):

in the `then` callbacks, you could define some timeouts, setting different timeout values depending on which should resolve first/last

```
const delay = (ms) => () => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms))
axios.request('get', url1)
   .then(delay(10))
   .then(() => { do something }); // resolves first
axios.request('get', url2)
   .then(delay(20))
   .then(() => { do something else }); // resolves last
```

edit...

I just realised this is probably your production code, not test code.  Either way you could apply the same thing to axios mock, i.e. apply a delay to a chained `then` callback

Comment: Yes tihs is my production code so there is no way to add delays. I have to think about how I could add deleys to the mock implementation...